# How to create a URL like "http://paramter1.xyz.com/"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How to create a URL where,the base URL contains a parameter. For example "blog.msdn.com". This "blog" is a parameter to the base URL "msdn.com". I want a URL like "blog.msdn.com", where "blog" is a parameter variable. How to create this type of URL pattern in MVC4.

Comment: I got answer to my question and it is all about having domain routing. it is clearly demonstrated here.
 http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/ASPNET-MVC-Domain-Routing.aspx

Answer (score -1):

in mvc you can  change your url of your site page like your domain /controller/view 
you can change character of after character of your domain  like your domain/instead of controller name/instead of view name